# How to remove effect of queryloader in a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I recently downloaded a template. But there are some coding in the "queryloader.js" that stops the page from opening(gives a blank screen) if I am not connected to the internet. And if i simply remove the linking to js file then the jquery animations in the site also disappears. Is there any way to load the page in local host with removing the jquery animations ?

Comment: you mean 'without' removing..?

Comment: i"m reallly sorry about it. Yes, "without" removing.